# Django upgraded from 1.10.x to 2.2.x. Now passwords are not working

Tags: django, passwords, django-admin

Is this a known issue?
Is there a way to circumvent this without changing passwords or asking users to reset the password?
I am using the Django-admin default app for the same. Please do ask what other information do you need to help me debug this.

FYI, I also upgrade from python 2.7.x to python 3.6.x for the same.

Comment: This is likely because they removed the `BCryptPassword` from the default `PASSWORD_HASHER` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/2.1/#removed-bcryptpasswordhasher-from-the-default-password-hashers-setting

Comment: Can you look in the database what hashing algorithm was used?

Comment: Passwords start with pbkdf2_sha256

Comment: what hashers are installed (in the `PASSWORD_HASHERS`)?

Comment: None.
I tried with PASSWORD_HASHERS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
]
But still doesn't work. debugged it too. but the hashes are indeed different.

Comment: What do you mean with "different". What is the prefix of `PBKDF2PasswordHasher`?

Comment: pbkdf2_sha256 for both the generated django 2.2.x password and the db entry created by django 1.10.x version

Comment: ah, but a hash can be different. Django will each time generate a random "seed", so if you use twice the same password, it will still end up with a different hash to avoid "rainbowtable attacks".

Comment: got it. any workarounds that i can use in the meanwhile?

Comment: do you use the standard login views?

Comment: Yes, standard views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely this is because they [removed the **`BCryptPasswordHasher`** from the default **`PASSWORD_HASHERS`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/2.1/#removed-bcryptpasswordhasher-from-the-default-password-hashers-setting) when they released [django-2.1](/questions/tagged/django-2.1). You can check this by looking into the database, and look if there are passwords that start with `bcrypt$$`.

You can add this manually to the [**`PASSWORD_HASHERS`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-PASSWORD_HASHERS) by adding:

```
# settings.py

# …

PASSWORD_HASHERS = [
    # …,
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptPasswordHasher'
]

# …
```

Comment: passwords start with pbkdf2_sha256